# Algebra & Re-arrangement

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to make this: $K(K+1)(2K+7) + 6(k+1)[(k+1)+2]/6$

Equal to this: $(K+1)[(k+1)+1][(2(k+1)+7]/6$  By using algebra and re-arrangement.

From the initial equation there should be just one more step before the two can equal each-other.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/697817/mathmatical-induction/697825#697825

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I literally just grabbed the link to do the same!

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, the OP probably should have edited his other question to emphasize that he was only asking about a particular algebraic step in a proof by induction, but I'm inclined to cut him some slack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be asking how to show

$$k(k+1)(2k+7)+{6(k+1)((k+1)+2)\over6}={(k+1)((k+1)+1)(2(k+1)+7)\over6}$$

The problem is, that's not the correct equation.  What you really want to show is

$${k(k+1)(2k+7)\over6}+(k+1)((k+1)+2)={(k+1)((k+1)+1)(2(k+1)+7)\over6}$$

Until you are fluent "speaking" algebra (and sometimes even then!), this is best done incrementally, in bite-sized steps:

$$\begin{align}
{k(k+1)(2k+7)\over6}+(k+1)((k+1)+2)
&={k(k+1)(2k+7)+6(k+1)(k+3)\over6}\\
&={(k+1)\left((2k^2+7k)+(6k+18)\right)\over6}\\
&={(k+1)\left(2k^2+13k+18\right)\over6}\\
&={(k+1)\left(k+2\right)\left(2k+9\right)\over6}\\
&={(k+1)\left((k+1)+1\right)\left(2(k+1)+7\right)\over6}\\
\end{align}$$

One other comment:  The mixing of uppercase $K$ and lowercase $k$ in the OP's formulation is inappropriate here, but that's a separate issue which, I think, stems from some uncertainty over how to write an inductive proof, which this algebra question originated in.

Comment: Yes, I was just asking for that certain step but believed the whole equation was necessary for people to understand what was going on, I should have emphasized a little better.